# How to enable linux ADB connection on marshmallow when USB debugging is enabled?

Tags: adb, linux, usb-connection-mode

How to enable linux ADB connection on  marshmallow when USB debugging is enabled ?
I've an android TV Leelbox S1 and Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32. When it's starting I can see the SUB entry  a cup of minutes before it's gone:

```
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 1b8e:c003 Amlogic, Inc.
```

Without this entry in the result of "lsusb", I don't see how  this connection could be done.
The USB debugging is enabled in developer options. I Don't know what did I miss.

Thank for any help.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Are you saying that the device is listed in `lsusb` while it is booting up, but once it has booted it is no longer listed? Are you able to see it in `adb devices` during the time that it shows up in `lsusb`?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, I going to respond at the first question : Are you saying that the device is listed in lsusb while it is booting up, but once it has booted it is no longer listed? yes it is and I'm not able to see any devices with adb command during and after the boot if the android device.

Answer (score 0):

You just enable USB debugging and than connect devica via USB to PC, and on PC you'll have to get adb binary 
[click](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads/)
Also maybe you'll need drivers for your device on PC.

Comment: USB debugging is already enabled Please read the question

Comment: Did you downloaded files from link which I give you?

Comment: However thank to answer and yes => `platform-tools$ ./adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36`  I got `error: no devices/emulators found`  as the usb devices is gone from the lsusb command result. I don't believe the problem is coming from my PC. It should coming from the android device. Thank